# Print job is starting in the middle or where I left off when I move to a new record unless I reload the form

Tags: vb.net

I've been learning to code for the last year.  This question might have been answered, but I can't seem to string the write combo together to google the answer up.

I'm trying to print a multi-page set of forms from a windows form.  Think Open Enrollment forms for the year for each employee at my organization.  I can get all the forms to print, but when I move to the next record, the print job seems to start where the e.hasmorepages=false left off.  I'm getting a blank page.  I've got a few combos depending on what they chose.  If the next record happens to have a different combo- it prints fine.  It's when it comes back to one of the combos that has already printed I get the blank page.  It's like the print sub doesn't exit fully.

I've tried "Exit Sub" and "Return" in multiple locations throughout my code.  Nothing seems to work.
I'm posting some code below, know that this is very abbreviated as my actual code is like 15,000 rows long.

```
      Imports System.Drawing.Printing
    
        Public Class PrintOEForms
        Dim PrintAll As Integer = 0
            Dim Print1 As Integer = 0
    
    Private Sub cmdPrintDocs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdPrintDocs.Click
    
        If cbUpdate911.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateCheckRel.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateW4.Checked = True AndAlso cbOE22.Checked = True AndAlso cbNoIns.Checked = True Then
                    PrintDocAll.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)
                    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocAll
                    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                        PrintDocAll.Print()
    ****'I've tried "Exit Sub" and "Return" here****  
                    End If
    
    
                    PrintDialog2.Document = PrintDocAll                
                End If
    
    If cbUpdate911.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateCheckRel.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateW4.Checked = True AndAlso cbOE22.Checked = True AndAlso cbNoIns.Checked = True Then
                    PrintDoc1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)
                    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDoc1
                    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                        PrintDoc1.Print()
                    End If
                    PrintDialog2.Document = PrintDoc1pdf               
                End If
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub PrintDocAll_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocAll.PrintPage
    
            Select Case PrintAll
                
                Case 0
                    'Confidential Cover Sheet
                    
                    e.HasMorePages = True
               
                Case 1
                    'Ins Options
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pbInsOptions.BackgroundImage, 50 + 15, 50 + 20)
                   
                    e.HasMorePages=True

               Case 2
                   'Ins Pg1
                   e.Graphics.DrawImage(pbIns1.Image, 13, 15)
                
                    e.HasMorePages = True
   

               Case 3
                   'Ins Pg2
                   e.grahics.DrawImage(pbIns2.Image, 13,15)
    
                   e.HasMorePages = True
    
            End Select

             PrintAll += 1
    End Sub
    
  Private Sub PrintDoc1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDoc1.PrintPage

        Select Case Print1
            
            Case 0
                'Confidential Cover Sheet
                
                e.HasMorePages = True
           
            Case 1
                'Ins Options
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pbInsOptions.BackgroundImage, 50 + 15, 50 + 20)
               
            Case 2
                'Ins Pg1
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(pbIns1.Image, 13, 15)
                
                    e.HasMorePages = False  

    **'I've tried "Exit Sub" and "Return" here**  
            
          End Select
    
            Print1 += 1
        End Sub
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    PrintDocAll.Print()
End If
```

To this:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    PrintAll = 0
    PrintDocAll.Print()
End If
```

and this:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    PrintDoc1.Print()
End If
```

to this:

```
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Print1 = 0
    PrintDoc1.Print()
End If
```

Otherwise those values are not reset after each document and you'll start the next one after already advancing to the end of the sequence.

Comment: OMG I love you! this solved the problem! Here is a virtual cookie and a virtual beverage of your choice!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initialize the printDocument object? Perhaps changing

```
    If cbUpdate911.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateCheckRel.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateW4.Checked = True AndAlso cbOE22.Checked = True AndAlso cbNoIns.Checked = True Then
                PrintDocAll.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

into:

```
    If cbUpdate911.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateCheckRel.Checked = True AndAlso cbUpdateW4.Checked = True AndAlso cbOE22.Checked = True AndAlso cbNoIns.Checked = True Then

                PrintDocAll = new PrintDocument
                PrintDocAll.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

In the following procedure:

```
Private Sub PrintDocAll_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocAll.PrintPage

        Select Case PrintAll
            Case 0
            Case 1
           Case 2
           Case 3
               'Ins Pg2
               e.grahics.DrawImage(pbIns2.Image, 13,15)

               e.HasMorePages = True ' This should be = False 

        End Select

         PrintAll += 1
End Sub
```

In Case 3, set e.HasMorePages to False. Also, before printing reset PrintAll to zero.

Comment: not sure what you were thinking would follow the new but it didn't like that.  :)  I tried all the suggestions it gave me and still didn't work :/

Comment: It could be PrintDocAll = new PrintDocument or, in case PrintDocAll is an object -lets say myPrintDoc that inherits from printDocument, then PrintDocAll = new myPrintDoc.

Comment: ok- I had already tried those.  PrintDocument and PrintDocAll and any combination I could think of.

Comment: Case 3, as you may see in my post, e.HasMorePages should be False.